# Improved Tic Tac Toe game. Made in C

Tags: c, tic-tac-toe

For my second week of learning C, I decided to remake the [Tic Tac Toe game I made last week](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/245132/simple-tic-tac-toe-game-inside-terminal), but in a different style (as some of you recommended me). This is my final product on the whole Tic Tac Toe game idea, so I tried my best. I feel like it is a bit overkill, but I want to know your opinion.

Here is the code:

```
/*
 * TESTED IN LINUX - 2020
 * 
 * This is my version of Tic Tac Toe, with an expandable board.
 * The standard size for the board is 3x3,
 * but it can be changed (only editing the script for now) to a 5x5, 7x7...
 * To expand the board you need to change the first 2 sizes of the 'board' array,
 * and by changing the 'boardSqrt' var to the same value as the first two.
*/


// Including needed stuff
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

// Creating the board struct
struct TTT_BoardGame {
    unsigned short playerTurn;
    int boardSqrt;
    double boardLen;
    bool canFinish;
    char board[3][3][3];
};

// Initializing the board struct
struct TTT_BoardGame ttt_init(void) {
    struct TTT_BoardGame game = {};
    game.playerTurn = 0;
    game.boardSqrt = 3;
    game.boardLen = game.boardSqrt * game.boardSqrt;
    game.canFinish = false;
    
    // Set the starting value in each board cell
    char pos[3] = {'0', '0', '1'};
    for (unsigned short v = 0; v < game.boardSqrt; v++) {
        for (unsigned short h = 0; h < game.boardSqrt; h++) {
        for (short p = 2; p >= 0; p--) {
            game.board[v][h][p] = pos[p];
        }
        if (pos[2] < '9')
                pos[2]++;
            else {
                pos[2] = '0';
                pos[1]++;
            }

            if (pos[1] > '9') {
                pos[1] = '0';
                pos[0]++;
            }
        }
    }
    return game;
}

// The menu that displays when starting the game
void ttt_startMenu(void) {
    char key;
    system("clear");
    printf("Tic tac toe game.\n\nTip: When prompted, each player needs to choose a spot to place their symbol.\nPress the 'Enter' key to continue... ");
    scanf("%c", &key);
}

// Returns the symbol of the current player
char ttt_currentPlayerTurn(struct TTT_BoardGame *game) {
    return game->playerTurn % 2 ? 'O' : 'X';
}

// Returns the symbol of the player before the one now
char ttt_lastPlayerTurn(struct TTT_BoardGame *game) {
    return game->playerTurn % 2 ? 'X' : 'O';
}

// Asks the current player for a position
char *ttt_askForPosition(struct TTT_BoardGame *game) {
    static char pos[3];

    printf("Choose a position for '%c': ", ttt_currentPlayerTurn(game));
    scanf("%s", pos);
    
    return pos;
}

// Checks if the spot chosen by the player is empty
bool ttt_isLegalMove(struct TTT_BoardGame *game, unsigned short col, unsigned short row) {
    if ((row + 1) <= game->boardSqrt && (col +1) <= game->boardSqrt) {
        if (game->board[col][row][1] != 'X' && game->board[col][row][1] != 'O')
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Edit the board cell to display the symbol of the current player
void ttt_markAnswer(struct TTT_BoardGame *game) {
    char *ans = ttt_askForPosition(game);

    for (unsigned short col = 0; col < game->boardSqrt; col++){
        for (unsigned short row = 0; row < game->boardSqrt; row++) {
        if (strncmp(ans, game->board[col][row], 3) == 0) {
            if (ttt_isLegalMove(game, col, row)) {
                    game->board[col][row][0] = ' ';
                    game->board[col][row][2] = ' ';
                    game->board[col][row][1] = ttt_currentPlayerTurn(game);
                    game->playerTurn++;
            break;
                }   
                else {
                    ttt_markAnswer(game);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Prints one row of board cells
void ttt_displayBoardSegment(struct TTT_BoardGame *game, unsigned short vPos) {
    for (unsigned short v = 0; v < 3; v++) {
        if (v % 2 == 0) {
            for (unsigned short h = 0; h < game->boardSqrt; h++)
                printf("|=====|");
        } else {
            for (unsigned short h = 0; h < game->boardSqrt; h++)
                printf("| %c%c%c |", game->board[vPos][h][0], game->board[vPos][h][1], game->board[vPos][h][2]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

// Prints as many board cell rows as needed
void ttt_displayBoardTotal(struct TTT_BoardGame *game) {
    system("clear");
    printf("Tic Tac Toe %dx%d\n\n", game->boardSqrt, game->boardSqrt);
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < game->boardSqrt; i++)
        ttt_displayBoardSegment(game, i);
}

// Checks if the game ended in a draw
bool ttt_testForDraw(struct TTT_BoardGame *game) {
    return game->playerTurn >= game->boardLen;
}

// Checks for rows with each cell full of one symbol
bool ttt_isHorizontalWin(struct TTT_BoardGame *game) {
    for (unsigned short v = 0; v < game->boardSqrt; v++) {
        char elem = game->board[v][0][1];
        for (unsigned short h = 0; h < game->boardSqrt; h++) {
            if (elem != game->board[v][h][1])
                break;
            if (h == game->boardSqrt - 1) {
                if (elem == 'X' || elem == 'O')
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Checks for columns with each cell full of one symbol
bool ttt_isVerticalWin(struct TTT_BoardGame *game) {
    for (unsigned short h = 0; h < game->boardSqrt; h++) {
        char elem = game->board[0][h][1];
        for (unsigned short v = 0; v < game->boardSqrt; v++) {
            if (elem != game->board[v][h][1])
                break;
            if (v == game->boardSqrt - 1) {
                if (elem == 'X' || elem == 'O')
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Checks one diagonal (top left -> bottom right) with each cell full of one symbol 
bool ttt_isDiagonalWinLeftToRight(struct TTT_BoardGame *game) {
    char elem = game->board[0][0][1];

    for (unsigned short v = 0, h = 0; v < game->boardSqrt; v++, h++) {
        if (elem != game->board[v][h][1])
            break;
        if (h == game->boardSqrt - 1) {
            if (elem == 'X' || elem == 'O')
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Checks other diagonal (top right -> bottom left) with each cell full of one symbol
bool ttt_isDiagonalWinRightToLeft(struct TTT_BoardGame *game) {
    unsigned short lastPosRow = game->boardSqrt - 1;
    char elem = game->board[0][lastPosRow][1];

    for (unsigned short v = 0, h = game->boardSqrt - 1; v < game->boardSqrt; v++, h--) {

        if (elem != game->board[v][h][1])
            break;
        if (h == 0) {
            if (elem == 'X' || elem == 'O')
                return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}

// All of the 'win' possibilities combined
bool ttt_testForWin(struct TTT_BoardGame *game) {
    if (ttt_isVerticalWin(game) || ttt_isHorizontalWin(game) || ttt_isDiagonalWinLeftToRight(game) || ttt_isDiagonalWinRightToLeft(game))
        return true;
}

// Checks if somebody won or the game ended in a draw
bool ttt_finishGame(struct TTT_BoardGame *game) {
    if (ttt_testForWin(game) && game->canFinish) {
        printf("\n'%c' won!\n", ttt_lastPlayerTurn(game));
        return true;
    }
    else if (ttt_testForDraw(game) && game->canFinish) {
        printf("\nDraw!\n");
        return true;
    }
    else if (ttt_testForWin(game) || ttt_testForDraw(game)) {
        game->canFinish = true;
    }
    return false;
}


// 'main' function
int main() {
    ttt_startMenu();
    
    for (struct TTT_BoardGame game = ttt_init();;) {
        ttt_displayBoardTotal(&game);

        if (!game.canFinish)
            ttt_markAnswer(&game);

    if (ttt_finishGame(&game))
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What do you think? Can I optimize it even more?

P.S: I also made a [GitHub project](https://github.com/FlipFlop-NotBot/TTT-SimpleGame) where I put my old game and my new one.

Comment: Here is the GH page: https://github.com/FlipFlop-NotBot/TTT-SimpleGame

Answer (score 7):

### Returning by reference

`ttt_init` makes an instance of your `TTT_BoardGame` but that instance has to be copied when returning it. This cannot be done efficiently. Your struct is so trivially small that no performance impact can be noticeable, but since you're expressly doing this for learning, it's worth pursuing the idiomatic method instead:

Either accept a pointer to the struct and initialize that (preferable), or `malloc` memory for a structure, initialize it and return its pointer. The first way will allow for a top-level function to allocate on the stack instead of the heap, which will be simpler for you.

### Indentation

Starting with this line:

```
for (short p = 2; p >= 0; p--) {
```

your indentation is incorrect. Consider using an auto-formatter.

### Constant references

This:

```
char ttt_currentPlayerTurn(struct TTT_BoardGame *game) {
```

should accept a `const` argument instead, since `game` is not and should not be modified.

### Non-re-entrant buffers

```
static char pos[3];
return pos;
```

is dangerous. That means that whenever you ask for a position, regardless of game state, you use one buffer for the entire process. That will lead to unexpected behaviour for callers. Instead, either accept a pre-allocated buffer pointer (preferable), or `malloc` one and return it.

### Combined boolean expression

```
if ((row + 1) <= game->boardSqrt && (col +1) <= game->boardSqrt) {
    if (game->board[col][row][1] != 'X' && game->board[col][row][1] != 'O')
        return true;
}
return false;
```

can be

```
return row + 1 <= game->boardSqrt
    && col + 1 <= game->boardSqrt
    && game->board[col][row][1] != 'X'
    && game->board[col][row][1] != 'O';
```